# Parse JSON file with Python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I trying to import a nested JSON file. I am using Python 3.0 
The JSON file looks like this

```
 "funds": [
    {
      "branch": "****",
      "controlDigits": "**",
      "accountNumber": "7605390244",
      "balance": {
        "amount": "71.1",
        "currency": "EUR"
      },
      "fundName": "Eurobits Funds 0",
      "webAlias": "Eurobits Funds 0",
      "performance": "4.41",
      "performanceDescription": "",
      "yield": {
        "amount": "0.0",
        "currency": "EUR"
      },
      "quantity": "10.00",
      "valueDate": "30/03/2017",
      "transactions": [
        {
          "operationType": "1",
          "operationDescription": "MOVILIZACION HACIA DENTRO",
          "operationDate": "30/03/2017",
          "fundName": "B EVOLUCION PRUDEN",
          "quantity": "-809.27",
          "unitPrice": "7.98",
          "operationAmount": {
            "amount": "-6457.97",
            "currency": "EUR"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

I am using this code:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
data_json = open("prueba.json",mode='r', encoding="utf8").read().replace('\n', '').replace('\t', '')
data_python = json.loads(data_json)

json_normalize(data_python['funds'])
```

this code works fine but field transaction is not expanded

In order to expand transactions I have tried this:

```
json_normalize(data_python,['funds','transactions'])
```

The information from transactions is expanded but I loose the other information
Besides that, the field amount looks like this:

{'amount': '1.00', 'currency': ''}

and I am not able to get it into separate fields

My question is how can I combine all the information into a single dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

Try `d['funds'][0]['transactions']` instead, where d is the name of your dictionary.

Comment: Thank you I get transactions expanded but how can I add information from funds like 'accountNumber'?

Comment: I have used the following code: json_normalize(data_python['funds'][0]['transactions'])

Comment: That's another query. `d['funds'][0]['accountNumber']`

Comment: Any ideas in how to combine both queries into a single dataframe?